# I'm looking for a way to search for and delete files which end in a specific character

Tags: directory

I have a large ebook library which I have somehow managed to duplicate. Each .pdf is stored within its own individual folder inside a directory.

The pdf's have been duplicated in their original location, and have an identical file name except with a "2" at the end of each file name.

Is there a way to automatically delete all files within a directory, and all subdirectories, whose file name ends with a "2"?

For example, in one directory there are two files:

"Tolle_2001_thepowerofnow.pdf"
"Tolle_2001_thepowerofnow2.pdf"

I would like to delete the second file, but there are thousands of these folders in my ebook directory.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you specify which Operating System - Linux, OSx, Windows? This will help clarify which solutions can be used to solve the issue. If on Linux using grep with a regex should  provide you with a list of all the files. passing this list into a deletion option with xargs should work. Test first on a low level folder (after taking backups of all folders,,,)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using Windows.